# How can I work with my list after using orderByChild?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I'm building an app that in which users can make posts and then vote on them. I want to be able to request the list of posts from firebase and order them by vote count. How can I do this?

My data is structure like this:

[image]

I'm attempting to fire this action:

```
export const fetchPostsByHottest = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref('/social/posts')
      .orderByChild('vote_count')
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({ type: HOT_POSTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
      });
  };
};
```

It just comes back in the normal order, by push key.

I've been told that snapshot.val() converts the snapshot into a regular JS object and kills any order.

This is my reducer:

```
import {
  HOT_POSTS_FETCH_SUCCESS,
} from '../actions/FeedActions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case HOT_POSTS_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I then try to map the state to props in my `feed` component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const posts = _.map(state.hotFeed, (val, uid) => {
    return { ...val, uid };
  });

  return { posts: posts.reverse() };
};
```

I do it like this as I need to get both the Value AND the UID from each of the post objects.

If I try and do turn it into an array in the action like this:

```
export const fetchPostsByHottest = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref('/social/posts')
      .orderByChild('vote_count')
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        const nodes = [];
        snapshot.forEach(child => nodes.push(child.val()));

        console.log(nodes);
        dispatch({ type: HOT_POSTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: nodes });
      });
  };
};
```

Then it will only bring me back one of the posts and it won't give me the UID either.

How can I work around this? :S

Thank you!

Matt

Comment: You dont get the UID because the UID is the key. it will be accessible using snapshot.key. Read the documentation for forEach here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query in your last snippet should be correct. There is no reason it should return only a single post. However, it's possible that the snapshot's [`forEach`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) is being short-circuited:

> The callback can return true to cancel further enumeration.

`push` returns the new length and it's possible that `forEach` is testing for any truthy value - not just `true` - and is cancelling further enumeration. Use a block to ensure `undefined` is returned.

Also, you can obtain the key using the child's `key` property.

```
firebase.database().ref('/social/posts')
  .orderByChild('vote_count')
  .once('value', snapshot => {

    const nodes = [];
    snapshot.forEach(child => { nodes.push({ ...child.val(), key: child.key }); });

    console.log(nodes);
    dispatch({ type: HOT_POSTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: nodes });
  });
```

Also, for your use case, `once` seems more appropriate than `on`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to use once as I want the feed to watch the posts and update automatically. 

I have the same code as you and it's definitely only returning one post though!

Comment: What do you mean by using a block to ensure undefined is returned? and why would it do so?

Comment: The block is the curly braces here: `child => { nodes.push(...); }`. Without them, the return value from `push` is returned by the arrow function - which might cancel further enumeration (as mentioned in the answer).

Comment: Oh brilliant, I missed that, thank you! Can you please explain exactly how this works? Why would it return something undefined? and how do the blocks help? Why do they?

Comment: It's just the arrow function syntax, that's all. `(x) => x + 1` is equivalent to `(x) => { return x + 1; }`, so `(x) => y.push(x)` is equivalent to `(x) => { return y.push(x); }`. So to avoid returning a value, an explicit block is required `(x) => { y.push(x); }`. It's only necessary because `forEach` is checking the return value.